# Java exception detected in safari but not detected in IE?

Tags: java, internet-explorer, nullpointerexception, safari

I have a java applet code that works fine when it's opened from IE, but if it's opened from Safari, Java console produces a nullpointerexception.

The code that generate this behaviour is shown below:

```
public class MsgBoxPanel extends JDialog
{

  Panel panel1 = new Panel();
  JLabel label1 = new JLabel();
  JLabel label2 = new JLabel();

  public MsgBoxPanel() 
  {
     try 
     {
        jbInit();
     }
     catch(Exception e) 
     {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
  }

  private void jbInit() throws Exception 
  {
     this.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
     this.setLayout(null);

     label1.setFont(common.COMPONENTS_FONT);
     label2.setFont(common.COMPONENTS_FONT);

     label2.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
     label2.setText("Buy");
     label2.setBounds(new Rectangle(0, -5, 400, 44));

     label1.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
     label1.setText("Are you sure?");
     label1.setBounds(new Rectangle(0, 0, 400, 44));

     panel1.setLayout(null);

     panel1.add(label1, null);
     panel1.add(label2, null);
  }

  public void setBounds(int x,int y,int width,int height)
  { 
      super.setBounds(x,y,width,height);
      this.setLayout(null);

     panel1.setBounds(4,6,this.getSize().width-8,this.getSize().height-12);

     this.add(panel1);

  }
}
```

When I call the applet from Safari (Mac OSX), java console shows the following exception:

```html
network: Created version ID: 1.8.0.45
      network: Created version ID: 1.8.0.45
      security: continue with running version
      network: Created version ID: 1.8.0.45
   network: Created version ID: 1.8
   network: Created version ID: 8.0.45
   basic: exception: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException.
   java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.awt.AWTAppletAdapter.runOnEDTAndWait(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.awt.AWTAppletAdapter.instantiateApplet(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.initAppletAdapter(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.awt.OldPluginAWTUtil.invokeAndWait(Unknown Source)
    ... 5 more
   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at mutajara.MsgBoxPanel.setBounds(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.move(Component.java:2101)
    at java.awt.Component.setLocation(Component.java:2090)
    at java.awt.Window.setLocation(Window.java:921)
    at java.awt.Window.init(Window.java:510)
    at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:436)
    at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:591)
    at java.awt.Dialog.<init>(Dialog.java:665)
    at java.awt.Dialog.<init>(Dialog.java:409)
    at javax.swing.JDialog.<init>(JDialog.java:272)
    at javax.swing.JDialog.<init>(JDialog.java:206)
    at javax.swing.JDialog.<init>(JDialog.java:154)
    at mutajara.MsgBoxPanel.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at mutajara.MainApplet.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.awt.AWTAppletAdapter$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:301)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
   Ignored exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
   basic: Dialog type is not candidate for embedding
```

To solve this exception, I detected that the main cause is that panel1 instance is null, once I added this peice of code to the setBounds method, the code runs correctly from safari.

here's the modified setBounds Method:

```html
public void setBounds(int x,int y,int width,int height)
{
  super.setBounds(x,y,width,height);
  this.setLayout(null);
    
  //This if statement solved the exception
  if(panel1 == null)
  {
  return;
  }
  
  panel1.setBounds(4,6,this.getSize().width-8,this.getSize().height-12);
   
  this.add(panel1);
   
}
```

**Would you please clarfiy for me why this behaviour happened, and why panel1 instance variable is null.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you extend another class in Java, your class properties (e.g. `panel1`) are not initialised until *after* the super constructor has finished.

I guess part of `JDialog's` construction involves calling `setBounds`.  You've overridden this method, so that call hits your overridden `setBounds`. Now, because `JDialog` is still in its construction phase, your `panel1` hasn't been created and initialised yet.  So you get your null-pointer-exception.

You have bigger problems though.  `setBounds` can be called a lot during runtime.  You don't want to be removing and re-adding your panel every time.
I would move these lines out of `setBounds` and into the top of your `jbInit` method instead:

```
 this.setLayout(null);
 this.add(panel1);
```

---

**Update**

You could keep your panel1.setBounds in there:

```
public void setBounds(int x,int y,int width,int height) { 
    super.setBounds(x,y,width,height);
    if (panel1 != null) {
       panel1.setBounds(4,6,this.getSize().width-8,this.getSize().height-12);
    }
}
```

Or, instead of positioning your components yourself, you could get Swing to do it for you by using a LayoutManager:

```
//this.setLayout(null);
this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
this.add(panel1);
// could use panel1.setBorder(...) to get your spacing around the outside
```

Comment: Mr Spoon, Thank you for your analysis, but what is the best place for panel1.setBounds (Since you advice me to move this.setLayout and this.add to jbInit)

Comment: @ManKeer have added an update - that can stay in setBounds.  Or you could simplify things by using a layoutmanager